# How to map array form observable to another array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-observables

I am currently using `this.route.url.subscribe(params=>...` to do something with my route parameters. I want to check if some parameters are in the subscribed param array. But this array contains `URLSegments` from which I only want to check for the `path` attribute. Is there any way I can remap this with a `map` operator?
I tried remapping the whole array like `this.route.url.map(x=>x.path)` but that does not work because the array itself has no `path`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 9):

Just call `map` also on the array:

```
this.route.url.map(x=>x.map(p => p.path))
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you for helping me out everytime :)

Answer (score 2):

> How to map array form observable to another array

You would actually map an observable to another observable using `map` (also called `select`).

## More

Select docs : https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/select.md

Comment: Are there any advantages over Günter`s solution?